# Android app crashes when pressing a button in landscape

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, android-orientation

The app crashes when I rotate to landscape and press a button on the main activity. It doesn't crash if I press the button in portrait, switch to landscape in the secondary activity, and then comeback to the main activity in landscape. It will crash when I press that button in landscape and I have no idea how or why it is doing that.

Are there any other files you may need to see? Please let me know, first time posting here.

This is the xml code in the main activity for the button

```
<Button 
            android:id="@+id/button_acknowledgements"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/acknowledgments"
            android:onClick="acknowledgments"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

This is the method in the mainactivity.java file that creates the new activity

```
public void acknowledgments(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Acknowledgments.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is all there is in the activity_aknowledments.xml file

```
<WebView 
        android:id="@+id/AckWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

This is what is in the Acknowledgments.java file

```
package com.example.spacepowerexchangeordersubmission;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Acknowledgments extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acknowledgments);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.AckWebView);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); 
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~rpanjwani3/");

    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.acknowledgments, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

I also included the  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" qualifier in the android manifest under the activity

```
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spacepowerexchangeordersubmission/com.example.spacepowerexchangeordersubmission.Acknowledgments}: java.lang.NullPointerException`
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at            dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at com.example.spacepowerexchangeordersubmission.Acknowledgments.setupActionBar(Acknowledgments.java:35)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at com.example.spacepowerexchangeordersubmission.Acknowledgments.onCreate(Acknowledgments.java:19)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-09 17:59:08.198: E/AndroidRuntime(22749):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: stack trace, error message??

Comment: Take out `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` it's a hack which even Google say should only be used as a last resort and only when you really know what your're doing.  Instead, read about and learn the Activity life cycle and code according to that, else you will just hide other bugs with the hack. Secondly, edit your question and include the stack trace from logcat.